# Получить с помощью JavaScript id div элемента внутри которого выделен мышкой текст если такое возможно

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom, firefox

Подскажите можно ли используя JavaScript захватить div элемент внутри которого выделен мышкой текст?

То есть у меня идёт цепочка div элементов(отрисовывается с помощью их таблица) если в нём выделен текст, причом нужно чтобы не важно как было выделено, даже если стандартным поисков Firefox. Можно ли захватить в последнем случаи div элемент?

Если возможно не во всех браузерах, то интересует Firefox.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что выделение найденного поиском на странице - это на самом деле никакое не выделение, и никаких событий не генерирует.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите можно ли используя JavaScript захватить div элемент внутри которого выделен мышкой текст?

ну с мышью всё предельно просто, можно через mouseup. А вот про поиск, самому интересно :):

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main')
main.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>{
console.log(e.target.className)
})
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="block1">1212312312</div>
<div class="block2">gsdfgsdfgsdfg</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Про событие про поднятие клавиши мышки я знаю. Давайте предположим что событие уже пропущено или текст был выделен с помощью клавиатуры(то есть не поиском браузера а именно выделен самим пользователем). Как в этом случаи получить div элемент в котором находится текстовая нода?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection